# how to write a JavaScript Parser in java

Tags: java, javascript, parsing

I want to write parser for JavaScript.

What I figured it out that I need to use some sort of scanning each character and as soon as I interact with any `{`, I must track for the next `}` (closing braces).
For efficient usage I can use stack. 
Can anyone suggest me some better idea or approach to build a parser for JavaScript with Java?

Comment: This would help for a simple parser, but if you want it to be effective and fast it should use much more intelligent ways. In college I remember a course called "Compilers & Assemblers" all talking about such stuff.

Comment: I wouldn't like to go for those book as of now , then what algorithm I may follow

Comment: Then this simple way should do for now, and also consider Regex and Pattern matching.

Comment: No, *don't* consider regexps. That way lies madness. JavaScript is just as **impossible** to parse with regexps as [HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Regular expressions can validate regular languages, but JS is context free and ***can not be parsed with regexps***.

Comment: And before anyone brings up using those regex extensions that allow recognizing more than regular languages: No, those *may* work in theory but are just as much madness in practice. Just write a goddamn parser (the parser can be a few hundred lines of Python!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is a complete JavaScript engine written in Java, names [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). Obviously it has to include a parser, and it's open source, so you could have a look how it's done there.

I suspect that you'll find that parsing a language such as JavaScript is much more complex than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate using ANTLR - it is a tool which will allow you to generate parser classes in java or other languages, based on a grammar file which you write.  You will likely be able to find a grammar (or at least a partial grammar) for javascript online.

Antlr home page with tutorials - http://www.antlr.org/

If you're not familiar with the concept of grammars you may need to read up on them and on compiling; a good first start would likely be wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar

Answer (score 1):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) is the *de-facto* standard for building parser (not only in Java), and is also very easy to use (including Eclipse [plugin](http://antlreclipse.sourceforge.net)). Seems like there are some readily available [grammars](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/)